# PostgreSQL: Combine Select and Insert with returning ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a table `temp123` as

```
Column      |      Type         |       Modifiers
------------+-------------------+------------------------
id          | integer           | not null default nextval('temp12_id_seq'::regclass)
description | character varying |
```

I would like to combine the ID returned by

```
INSERT INTO temp123 (description) 
      VALUES ('TESTING') RETURNING ID;
```

with a `SELECT'. For example (doesn't work):

```
SELECT 23, x.* 
FROM (INSERT INTO temp123 (description) 
       VALUES ('TESTING') RETURNING id ) AS x;
```

PostgreSQL v9.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SELECT part is not needed in your example. The desired result would be obtained like this with any PG version that supports INSERT...RETURNING (>=8.2):

```
insert into temp123(description) values('TESTING') returning 23,*;
```